# string or binary data truncated after server reboot

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

After rebooting SQL Server 2005 Standard 9.0.3233, we have been experiencing the above error in some of our stored procedures which try to insert into a table variable from a specific column of a table.  The base table has the column defined as varchar(10), but the table variable has the column being inserted into defined only as varchar(3).  However, the SELECT statement only returns data with 3 or less characters.

We have not changed the data or the code base in any other way, and this is only happening on our production server.  If I run the same query on a test server with the same SQL Server 2005 edition installed, but an older backup, the error does not occur.  The same data is returned in both queries if the INSERT is removed, or the table variable column is extended to match the base table.

What I have noticed is that the execution plan is different when the same query is run on the two servers.  On the server where the query works, there is a computed scalar operation which takes the column and does an implicit conversion to varchar(3), before it is then outputted to the nested loop join operation.

On the server that returns an error, there is a hash join and table scan of the base table instead.  I have already tried to rebuild indices and update statistics on all tables involved, including using fullscan, and with the same stat_stream as in the server that works, but I can't get the same plan back.

For now we have fixed the few stored procedures which were broken by modifying the size of the table variable column, but I would like to know if there is a way to get the statistics and indices back so that they produce the same plans as before, in case there is more code out there which just hasn't executed yet.

Comment: The execution plan can never affect query correctness. Semantics can only change if you relied on undefined behavior. Maybe you are missing an ORDER BY so that different rows can validly be returned? Please post some code.

Answer (score 1):

This is known behavior and probably has nothing to do with your reboot.  Effectively what's happening is that the optimizer is re-ordering the logical elements of your query for performance reason, but this is resulting in the truncation-error check being done *before* the `WHERE` clause's filtering.

The recommended solution is to wrap the column expression that gets assigned to your VARCHAR(3) in a `CASE..` that duplicates the length test in your `WHERE` clause.  I know that sounds illogical, but it usually fixes the problem.